# What to reference for grammatical features being more reliable than lexical features for diachronic research?

Tags: grammar, reference-request, lexicon, diachronic

I often hear people mention in passing that grammatical features are more reliable than lexical features in diachronic research, specifically when detecting pseudepigraphs, because it is relatively easy to fake old lexicon but difficult to fake old grammar (as is evidenced anecdotally by people imitating old English but mixing "thee", "thou" and "thy").

If I were to mention this in my paper, who should I cite? Where can I read more about this hypothesis? Has there been any statistical analysis on it?

Comment: One wonders whether it is in fact easy to imitate old lexical items or just difficult to spot! Subjected to serious criticism, the slightly different uses of key words would probably reveal a lot about anachronicity. Unfortunately, we're good at unconsciously making accommodations for words to yield coherent readings...